# Calendar Carousel gives range error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

Calendar Carousel given me following error.It worked correctly before.Now It's not working I've tried flutter clean and switching the channel but error remaining same.

> ```
>  I/flutter (30661): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
>     I/flutter (30661): The relevant error-causing widget was:
>     I/flutter (30661):   Container 
>     lib\date.dart:53
>     I/flutter (30661): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>     I/flutter (30661): #0      List.[]  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:146:60)
>     I/flutter (30661): #1      _CalendarState._setDatesAndWeeks 
>     package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart:836
>     I/flutter (30661): #2      _CalendarState._setDate.<anonymous closure> 
>     package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart:854
>     I/flutter (30661): #3      State.setState 
>     package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1233
>     I/flutter (30661): #4      _CalendarState._setDate 
>     package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart:853
>     I/flutter (30661): #5      _CalendarState.initState
> ```

Here is the code,I've tried Calendar Carousel example It also gives me the same error.I don't know what causing this.

```
class BoxContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BoxContainerState createState() => _BoxContainerState();
}

DateTime _currentDate;

class _BoxContainerState extends State<BoxContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
    child: CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate = date);
      },
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
      customDayBuilder: (   
        bool isSelectable,
        int index,
        bool isSelectedDay,
        bool isToday,
        bool isPrevMonthDay,
        TextStyle textStyle,
        bool isNextMonthDay,
        bool isThisMonthDay,
        DateTime day,
      ) {
          
          if (day.day == 15) {
            return Center(
              child: Icon(Icons.local_airport),
            );
          } else {
            return null;
          }
      },
      weekFormat: false,
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      height: 420.0,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate,
      daysHaveCircularBorder: false, 
    ),
  );
}


}
```

Comment: can you share the code where you have initialized the calender carousel

Comment: I'll uodate.I've tried default example on pub.dev.But It also gives me that error.